# Mock a Wreq Response

Tags: haskell, httpresponse

I want to manually create a `Response` in order to mock a web server, similar to [this](https://blog.pusher.com/unit-testing-io-in-haskell/) blog post. However, the `Network.Wreq` library that I'm using doesn't reveal the constructor for `Response`. How do I create a `Response` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the sources](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/src/Network-Wreq.html) of *wreq* reveals that the `Response` type comes from the *http-client* library. That is the same library used by the blog post you link to, and so the solution is the same that, presumably, was used in the post: import `Network.HTTP.Client.Internal`, which [exports the constructor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Client-Internal.html#t:Response).

Comment: Well that function creates a response by making a request to the server so it doesn't really help. After digging in the *http-client* sources though I've found that `Response` is exported by `Network.HTTP.Client.Types`, which should be a part of the *http-client* package but doesn't appear to be so. Trying to import it makes stack complain about being unable to find the interface and searching for it on stackage gives no results.

Comment: I'm already doing that. `Network.HTTP.Client` does not reexport the `Response` constructor, only the type and the record getters. This prevents me from actually creating a value of the type and is at the crux of my problems.

Comment: @terratinkah My previous comment was indeed rather off the mark (I hadn't noticed a few things in the blog post), but the constructor is exported by `Network.HTTP.Client.Internal`. I will update the answer accordingly.